# competitive programming and input

Tags: java, io

I'm practicing for a competitive tournament that will be in my faculty in a few weeks, and thus I encountered a small problem.

**The competition restricted the use of java.io.*** (except IOException...)

I need to read (from stdin) input, each test case is separated with a blank line. end of test cases - when EOF is found.

I need to find a way to get data from IO, without using java.io

so far, I got this (which works) - it returns a string containing each test case, and null when I'm out of test cases.

```
public static String getInput() throws IOException {
    int curr=0;
    int prev=0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (true) {
        curr = System.in.read();
        if (curr == -1) { 
            return null; //end of data
        }
        if (curr == '\r') {
            curr = System.in.read();
        }
        if (curr == prev && curr == '\n') {
            return sb.toString(); //end of test case
        } //else:
        sb = sb.append((char)curr);
        prev = curr;
    }
}
```

performance (for the IO) is neglected, so I don't care I read only one byte every time.

**Question:** Is there a more elegant (shorter and faster to code) way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: If what you need is to read from stdin and not write that code in the program, a better approach would be to use the pwsh/cmd/bash functions directly from the terminal like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67654378/16003320)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following and make it efficient by wrapping the System.in.

```
public static String readLine() throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int ch; (ch = System.in.read()) > 0;)
        if (ch == '\r') continue;
        else if (ch == '\n') break;
        else sb.append(ch);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

EDIT: On Oracle JVM, System.in is a BufferedInputStream which wraps a FileInputStream which wraps a FileDescriptor. All these are in java.io.

Comment: BufferedInputStream and InputStream are both java.io . the instructions are specific - the java.io is restricted so we will not be able to use InputStream

Comment: System.in is an InputStream, so I guess you can't use that either. ;)  The method still works without the buffering.

Answer (score 9):

In fact, there are a few ways that you can process input in Java in competitive programming.

### Approach 1: Using `java.util.Scanner`

This is the simplest way to read input, and it is also really straightforward to use. It can be slow if you have a huge amount of input. If your program keeps getting TLE (Time Limit Exceeded), but your program has the correct time complexity, try reading input with the second or third approach.

Initialization `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`

### Reading an integer: `int n = sc.nextInt();` 
Approach 2: Using `java.io.BufferedReader`

Use this one if there is a huge amount of input, and when the time limit of the problem is strict. It does require some more work, involving splitting the input by spaces, or using `Integer.parseInt(str);` to extract integers from the input.

You can find a speed comparison here [https://www.cpe.ku.ac.th/~jim/java-io.html](https://www.cpe.ku.ac.th/%7Ejim/java-io.html)

Initialization: `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(System.in);`

Reading an integer: `int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());`

### Approach 3: Reading directly from `FileDescriptor` using custom reader

This approach is the fastest approach possible in Java. It does require a lot of work, including implementing the reader, as well as debugging should any problems arise. Use this approach if the time limit is strict and if you are allowed to bring code into the competition. This method is tested to be much faster than the second approach, but it would not usually provide you with an advantage since it is only about 2x the speed of the `BufferedReader` approach.

This is one implementation of such an approach written by my friend:
https://github.com/jackyliao123/contest-programming/blob/master/Utils/FastScanner.java

The usage of the reader really depends on your implementation of the reader. It is suggested to maintain one copy of the reader that is somewhat guaranteed to work, because the last thing you want in a contest is having a non-functional reader and debugging the rest of your program, thinking there are some bugs there.

Hope this helps and best wishes on your competition!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the `java.util.Scanner` class if `java.util` is allowed. It has useful methods for reading in a line, a token or even a number as needed. But it is slower than `BufferedReader` and possibly slower than using `System.in.read()` directly.

Since `System.in` implements the `InputStream` interface, it might also be some speedup to use `System.in.read(byte[] b)` to read in the input. This way you can read in a bunch of bytes at a time instead of just the one, which should be faster. But the added complexity of having to code and debug it during the contest might not be worth it.

Edit:
Searching the web I found someone discussing using `System.in.read(byte[] b)` in the [UVa forum](http://online-judge.uva.es/board/viewtopic.php?p=51618#p51618) back when UVa had terrible Java support.

Comment: to get an instance of Scanner I need a InputStream, which is forbidden

Comment: use `new Scanner (System.in);`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is also forbidden, but I'll try this out. I'll accept this answer if I get approval to use Scanner.

Comment: @amit gr: To get `Scanner` you only need to import from `java.util`. Furthermore, you don't have to create any `InputStream`, you just use the `InputStream` instance you already have - `System.in`. So, you would instantiate by `Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);`. If you can use `System.in` elsewhere, I don't see any reason why it can't be used here.

Comment: i'll check this out, and will accept this answer if it possible. thanks for the help anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use a scanner**

```
import java.util.Scanner;//put this above the class
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //this creates the scanner
int input = scanner.nextInt();
```

.nextInt() takes integers
.nextLine() takes strings