# How do I read input .in files in command line on windows

Tags: c++, powershell, cmd

I completed my code but the problem is I don't know how to test it based on instructions given.

The instructor provided us with `3` input files with the following values:

file1: `33 20`

file2: `5  7`

file3: `18 15`

I'm supposed to take these values and create event objects with these stored values. Problem is the instructor is giving the testing method on `Ubuntu` and she displayed how to input file in command line like:

```
 ./sApp < simulationShuffled3.in
```

So i'm just really confused as to how I'm suppose to get it working. I am currently using Windows console, VStudios and sublime text with a terminal attachment.

The code I'm currently using that's following from an example from my course notes is

```cpp
while (getline(cin >> ws, aLine)) {   // while (there is data)
    stringstream ss(aLine);
    ss >> arrivalTime >> processingTime;
    Event newEvent = Event('A',arrivalTime,processingTime);
    eventPriorityQueue.enqueue(newEvent);
}
```

Comment: could you check my answer too, I have corrected some of my mistakes since i first posted

Answer (score 3):

### Read input from `stdin` in Windows [&/or] Linux

You can do this in three ways:

1. In Command prompt (windows)
2. In Powershell (windows/linux)
3. In WSL & Linux

#### 1: in Windows Cmd

```
type input.in | python file_requiring_input.py              # in python

type input.in | go run file_requiring_input.go              # in go

type input.in | node file_requiring_input.js                # in js

javac file_requiring_input.java && 
type input.in | java file_requiring_input                   # in java

g++ file_requiring_input.cpp && 
type input.in | a.exe                                       # in cpp

gcc file_requiring_input.c && 
type input.in | a.exe                                       # in c
```

Another way

```
python file_requiring_input.py < input.in                   # in python

g++ file_requiring_input.cpp && 
a.exe < input.in                                            # in cpp
```

#### 2: in Powershell

```
gc .\input.in | python file_requiring_input.py              # in python

g++ .\file_requiring_input.cpp ; 
gc .\input.in | .\a.exe                                     # in cpp
```

> `gc` is short for `Get-Content`. Other aliases of `gc` are `cat` and `type`.
> which means that all three names can be used as replacement or gc

### 3: use [wsl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) for windows //Linux commands

```
cat input.in | python file_requiring_input.py                # in python

g++ file_requiring_input.cpp && 
cat input.in | ./a.out                                       # in cpp
```

another way

```
python file_requiring_input.py < input.in                    # in python

g++ file_requiring_input.cpp && 
./a.out < input.in                                           # in cpp
```

---

> have edited the code testing everything out hopefully. Do correct me if I am wrong or if anything more is to be added .
> Also input.in is more generally a text file so you can create input.txt file as you wish and it would work the same

Answer (score 1):

Well, as this is an assignment, I'm not going to provide you with a ready-made code. Rather, I'll just point you to the right direction.

In Windows, you can provide the arguments to your executable separated by space on `Command Prompt` like this:

```
C:\Assignment> Test.exe file1.in file2.in file3.in
```

And, it'll work on `Ubuntu` as well.

So, you need to study `Command Line Arguments`, `File Handling`, reading from file; and, you'll have to convert these strings read from files to integers.

**Command Line Arguments:** http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function

**File Handling:** http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream

**Here's a minimal example for reading from a file (`std::ifstream`):**

I've a test file at `C:\Test\Test.txt` with the following contents:

> 11 22
>   12 23
>   23 34

Here's is `main.cpp` to test it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    const std::string filename { R"(C:\Test\Test.txt)" };

    std::ifstream ifs { filename };
    if ( !ifs.is_open() )
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not open file!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int arrivalTime    { 0 };
    int processingTime { 0 };

    while ( ifs >> arrivalTime >> processingTime )
    {
        std::cout << "Arrival Time : " << arrivalTime << '\n'
                  << "Processing Time : " << processingTime << std::endl;
    }

    ifs.close();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> Arrival Time    : 11
>   Processing Time : 22
>   Arrival Time    : 12
>   Processing Time : 23
>   Arrival Time    : 23
>   Processing Time : 34

Comment: I followed one of the example codes from my course and it involves using stringstream ss(aLine) and it involves the same sort of input file method. I was thinking of arguments earlier but the code used doesn't really make use of it at all, is there perhaps some other resources i should look into for this solution

Comment: @Lawdevo: Kindly add this code in your question also. Now, you don't have to use `cin` because you'll be `read`ing from files. And, as your are only reading, you can use `std::ifstream` for it.

Comment: @Lawdevo: I've updated my answer with an example of `std::ifstream`. You don't have to use `std::sstream`.

Comment: It didn't really solve my problem, but it was one of the ideas I was thinking about and glad i had some sort of code insight on it. Turns out i just needed to do sApp.exe < input.in in command line with the use of the stringStream/getline in the code. Thanks for the help regardless though!

Comment: @Lawdevo: Sure. No problem at all!