# How to input all test cases and then output the result of all test cases at the end of the execution

Tags: c

I was attempting the [CodeChef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeChef) contest and I came across this problem. I solved the program, but the problem is that if I choose more than one test case. When I enter my first test case, I’m getting the solution for that right away. Instead I want it to input all the test cases and give solutions of all test cases at the end as asked in the question. What should I change in my code to do that?

[image][image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  int t, n, a, b, c, x, y, z;
  //printf("No. of test cases\n");
  scanf("%d", &t);
  for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
  {
    //printf("Enter three inputs\n");
    scanf("%d\t%d\t%d", &a, &b, &c);
    x = a + b;
    y = b + c;
    z = a + c;
    if(x>y && x>z)
    {
      printf("%d",x);
    }
    else if(y>a && y>z)
    {
      printf("%d", y);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("%d", z);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: These codechef tasks are designed in such a way that your "accumulation of test cases" is not necessary. Because it may be a bit complicated, and less fun than solving the actual task.

Comment: Where do you get that all the output needs to be generated at the end of the program? It is perfectly possible to output one line after a test case has been processed. The end result is the same.

Comment: @anatolyg So, are you saying the code should have run then also? even though i am getting outputs after every test cases. and can you suggest change in the code so i could get the outputs of all test cases at the end.

Comment: @Cheatah Can you suggest changes so that i could print the ouputs of all test cases at the end  as shown in the codechef image rather than printing them after every test cases.

Comment: Pipe them all into a file, then cat the file?

Comment: @MartinJames Can you explain how to do that in the answer section it would be a great help. thanks

Comment: No, I will not suggest any changes to print the output at the end. It is not necessary. It's a dumb idea and a waste of resources.

Comment: @Cheatah Then what do you think the error might be if this is not the case could you check my code? why is codechef not accepting it and claiming its wrong even though it works fine on the IDE

Comment: Outputting a newline character at the end of each line is probably a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if all you care about is to pass in the input and not get messy, I'd recommend you to try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67654378/16003320).

You would have to pass the input to a file, [let’s call it *input.txt*]:

```
2
4 2 8
10 14 18
```

And then call it as

```
gcc file.c
a.exe < input.txt
```

You might also want to add `\n` in the `printf` statement so that each answer appears in a separate line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int t,n,a,b,c,x,y,z;
  //printf("No. of test cases\n");
  scanf("%d",&t);
  for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
  {
    //printf("Enter three inputs\n");
    scanf("%d\t%d\t%d",&a,&b,&c);
    x=a+b;
    y=b+c;
    z=a+c;
    if(x>y && x>z)
      printf("%d",x);
    else if(y>a && y>z)
      printf("%d",y);
    else
      printf("%d",z);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

[image]

In cmd, *stack.c* is my file containing your code and *stack.in* is my input file.

Comment: `a.exe` is for `windows users`, if you are a `linux user` it would be `a.out` for you

Comment: Thanks for answering but i have never tried doing this ,and have no idea how to, do you mean i would sending my input into a file and then printing the output. can you do it in my code. it would be a great help thanks

Comment: I use windows in my system. and will this method work in competitions also like in codechef?

Comment: You need to have `gcc` install on your system, it is a compiler for c .Compiling c provides `a.exe` file . Everything else is in-built in the system

Comment: oh i see now thats why whenever im executing my programs in my vscode with name a.c it also generates file a.exe. i have gcc already installed in my system whats next

Comment: create an input file provide the input | compile and pass the input file to the c executable

Comment: This would do in my personal ide but im still not getting how would this be possible in online ide's like in codechef?

Comment: Is this not possible to make some change in the code that would print my outputs seperately?

Comment: it wouldnt work for online ide, I though you meant to try it in pc during your competition.

Comment: print my outputs seperately? – @AKSHAT KANT THAKUR ... I have added the code . Hope that helps

Comment: Dont forget to upvote the ans in the link provided if it proved useful

Answer (score 0):

Make a `struct` which holds the input data for each test case. Allocate (using `malloc`) an array for these test cases. Then pass over the array in a loop and do work for each test case.

```
struct TestCase
{
    int a, b, c;
};

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t); // t = number of test cases
    struct TestCase* test_cases = malloc(t * sizeof(TestCase));
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d\t%d\t%d", &test_cases[i].a, &test_cases[i].b, &test_cases[i].c);
    }
    // --------- Finished input; now do calculations -----------
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        int x=test_cases[i].a+test_cases[i].b;
        int y=test_cases[i].b+test_cases[i].c;
        int z=test_cases[i].a+test_cases[i].c;
        if(x>y && x>z)
        {
            printf("%d",x);
        }
        else if(y>a && y>z)
        {
            printf("%d",y);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d",z);
        }
    }
    free(test_cases);
}
```

Note how I replaced, e.g. `a` by `test_cases[i].a`. You need the more complicated access pattern because the code holds data for all test cases, instead of holding data for only current test case.

Comment: does this mean what i am asking is not possible in my code i have to change stuff in there , then only it would work. what if i don't want structures to be used? is there an easier solution possible for this?